# Flutter / Android: Start executable from assets

Tags: android, flutter, dart, process

In my flutter application I have an asset which is an executable and I like to start that as interactive child process on android. My Test-Code is like this:

```
rootBundle.load("assets/engines/stockfish-android-armv8").then((buffer) async {
      String name = "${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/stockfish-android-armv8";
      final File file = File(name);
      await file.writeAsBytes(buffer.buffer.asUint8List());

      ProcessResult p1 = Process.runSync("chmod", ["a+x", name]);
      ProcessResult p2 = Process.runSync(name, []);
}
```

So first the executable is copied from assets to Documents directory. Then its chmodded with a+x (or u+x, does not matter, exit code of that process is 0 -- so seems to be allright).

But when trying to start the process, it gives a `ProcessException: Permission denied Command: /data/user/0/com.example.chess_partner/app_flutter/stockfish-android-armv8`.

When the file is not chmodded, the exception is "Text File busy".

I am kind of out-of-ideas... anyone has a hint?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

In this case the process can be started by:

```
Process p2 = await Process.start(name, [], runInShell: true);
```

Running the process in a shell seems to be allowed.

Best Regards,
Tobias